# Css display:none is not applied in HTML mail generated in c#

Tags: asp.net

In my code I use the `MailMessage` class of .Net to generate mails.

I have set  `msg.IsBodyHtml = true;`. Still in the mail the CSS is not applied at all..

I want to hide some tags in mail. For that I have used `Display` property, But It doesn't work...

What should I do?

Comment: This very much depends on the email client. You should use inline CSS rather than in a stylesheet or in the `<head>` section. Can you show us your relevant source HTML/CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use a lot of CSS in your HTML emails.  Currently most email clients do not have full support for CSS, most likely for security reasons.  Take your case for example, it would not be wise for Outlook to allow someone to send me an email with hidden content in it.  There's too much room for malicious exploits that way.

For the best results, go a little old school with your HTML.  Use table layouts, limit the amount of images, and use sparse amounts of CSS in **inline styles only**.  In some cases, don't be afraid to revert back to classic HTML tags for styling, such as `<table bgcolor="#F30FF0"></table>`.

Comment: Thanks.. but actually based on the data from the database i need to show/hide some <tr> of html... for that i have used inline css,but unfortunately it is not working.. I m posting part of my html document below:

Comment: <tr id="" style="display:none;" >
   <td style="font-size: 17px; color: #000000; font-weight: bold; text-align:left; padding-left: 1px;">
    Photo #5<br />
    <img height="240" src="" width="320" /></td>
   <td style="font-size: 17px; color: #000000; font-weight: bold; text-align:left; padding-left: 1px;">
    Photo #6<br />
    <img height="240" src="" width="320" /></td>
  </tr>

Comment: I just outlined for you why it is probably not working, and probably won't be able to work.  Have you considered simply just not rendering the `<tr>` row that you don't want to show?  If you don't need to display it, is there any reason it should be in the email at all?

Comment: Thanks Mike..., I also found it feasible to not to display the <tr> which does not contain value. I managed it with HTMLDocument. And now my code is working fine.Actually it was the problem related to Mail Client.Some mail clients don't render some part of CSS properly.That's why I was facing the problem.Anyway now my code is working fine. Thanks again..

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. When you have a chance would you mind marking my response as the answer?